# Having difficulty mocking object returned by patched function

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-mock

I have an instance method on a Django form class that returns a Python object from a payment service if successful.

The object has an `id` property, which I then persist on a Django model instance.

I'm having some difficulty getting the mocked object to return its `.id` property correctly.

```
# tests.py

class DonationFunctionalTest(TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):

        with mock.patch('donations.views.CreditCardForm') as MockCCForm:
            MockCCForm.charge_customer.return_value = Mock(id='abc123')

            # The test makes a post request to the view here.

            # The view being tested calls:

            # charge = credit_card_form.charge_customer()
            # donation.charge_id = charge.id
            # donation.save()
```

However:

```
print donation.charge_id

# returns
u"<MagicMock name='CreditCardForm().charge_customer().id'
```

I expected to see "abc123" for the `donation.charge_id`, but instead I see a unicode representation of the `MagicMock`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by doing the patching a bit differently:

```
@mock.patch('donations.views.CreditCardForm.create_card')
@mock.patch('donations.views.CreditCardForm.charge_customer')
def test_foo(self, mock_charge_customer, mock_create_card):

    mock_create_card.return_value = True
    mock_charge_customer.return_value = MagicMock(id='abc123')

    # remainder of code
```

Now the id matches what I expect. I'd still like to know what I did wrong on the previous code though.